# Unit testing @Validated

Tags: java, spring, validation, junit

Looking for some help in unit testing while @Validated is being used.
I have two methods with following signature.
Here "A" and "B" are marker interfaces.

```
public void processA (@Validated(A.class) final MyRequest myRequest)

public void processB (@Validated(B.class) final MyRequest myRequest)
```

And MyRequest has validations on its attributes like this.

```
@NotBlank(groups = A.class)
@NotNull(groups = B.class)
private String id;
```

In my test cases, how can I introduce which marker interface the test cases should use and apply on the bean.

Cheers,

abk

Comment: This way you are testing the `@Validated` infrastructure, which is not necessary. You only should unit test your own code. Foreign code has to be assume to be tested.